# Enable multiple login(Facebook/twitter/Google+) in iphone app(xcode)

Tags: ios, facebook, twitter, google-plus, multiple-login

I am developing iphone application which has multiple login like this ex. Facebook,Twitter and Google+. Now i want to enable multiple login for same user.So i have a doubt that what can i do after user sign in with facebook and then twitter(without log out from facebook).I need suggestion like if user is logged in with facebook and then user want to login with twitter then i disable facebook sign in button?

I also have doubt that if in facebook profile user has name like "abc" and in twitter profile user has a name like "xyz" then which information do i keep in database of my app.Do i give priority to user for storing user information in database? like if there is conflict of name then i can give priority to user like 1st priority:facebook 2nd priority:twitter and so on.

Do i have to create seperate UI for setting priority?

Comment: i dont think so because you will not get password

Comment: Please clarify a little more.  Are you asking: 1) How you would support login / sign up from the major social platforms? 2) How to support connecting multiple social platforms at the same time (link my Google+, Twitter, and Facebook accounts ala Quara/LinkedIn)? 3) How to support multiple logins from a single platform (e.g. login with more than 1 Facebook account)?

Comment: thanks for your quick reply.it might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question:
Following parameters are considered:

1) How to support connecting multiple social platforms at the same time (link my Google+, Twitter, and Facebook accounts ala Quara/LinkedIn)? 
2)How you would support login / sign up from the major social platforms?
3) How to support multiple logins from a single platform (e.g. login with more than 1 Facebook account)?

Comment: This is literally a copy/paste from a comment by @class